# jquery javascript - determine focus of iframe parent wndows

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I determine the focus of the parent to an iframe, from the iframe.

Yes both the framed page and the container are on the same site and I have control over both.

```
$j('#captcha', window.top).focus(function(){
    $j( "#showit" ).delay(10000).toggle( "slide", {direction: "left" }, 2000  );
});
```

Basically my desired outcome is, when the parent window is in focus, do countdown and toggle "showit" from the child frame, if the window is not in focus, stop the countdown and stop toggle, when window comes back in focus, begin countdown again.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to have a handler for the onBlur event, such as:

```html
$j('#captcha', window.top).blur(function(){
    $j( "#showit" ).toggle( "slide", {direction: "right" }, 2000  );
});
```

Comment: that, also has no effect.

Comment: @Bruce When the focus handler has been activated ?